# A lot of crashes at Android vitals regarding Admob advertising

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

After upgrading Unity to version 2018.3.0f2 the number of errors related to advertising has dramatically increased. Build System was changed for Android becomes Gradle (Internal was before is deprecated now). Example of exception:

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [Thread-326575]
Unity version     : 2018.3.0f2
Device model      : Xiaomi Redmi Note 5
Device fingerprint: xiaomi/whyred/whyred:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/V10.0.6.0.OEIMIFH:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.nativeProxyInvoke (Native Method)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$1.invoke (Unknown Source:6)
  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke (Proxy.java:913)
  at $Proxy9.onAdFailedToLoad (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.unity.ads.RewardBasedVideo$1$1$2.run (RewardBasedVideo.java:89)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

Proxy number may be different: $Proxy9,$Proxy10,$Proxy12,$Proxy13
There are also such similar mistakes, but for the purchase of goods.

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [pool-2-thread-1]
Unity version     : 2018.3.0f2
Device model      : BQru BQru_BQru-5058
Device fingerprint: BQru/BQru-5058/BQru-5058:7.0/NRD90M/1494381105:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.nativeProxyInvoke (Native Method)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$1.invoke (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke (Proxy.java:813)
  at $Proxy7.OnProductsRetrieved (Unknown Source)
  at com.unity.purchasing.common.UnityPurchasing.OnProductsRetrieved (UnityPurchasing.java:24)
  at com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.GooglePlayPurchasing.NotifyUnityOfProducts (GooglePlayPurchasing.java:572)
  at com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.GooglePlayPurchasing.access$1000 (GooglePlayPurchasing.java:43)
  at com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.GooglePlayPurchasing$5.onQueryInventoryFinished (GooglePlayPurchasing.java:531)
  at com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.IabHelper$4.workWith (IabHelper.java:862)
  at com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.BillingServiceManager$2.run (BillingServiceManager.java:146)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
```

I use the code as in the documentation, before the transition to the new version of Unity everything worked without errors.

I tried to install different versions of AdMob plugin for Unity, different resolvers, added and deleted services in Unity.

Now in my Unity 2018.3.0f2:
- API minimum level: 16
- API target level: highest installed (level 28, was 27)
- Scripting Runtime version: .NET 4.x (was 3.5 - deprecared now)
- Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v3.15.1

Installed in system through SDK Manager:
- Android SDK Platform-Tools 28.0.1
- Android SDK Tools 26.1.1
- Google Play Services version 49

Unfortunately, I can not repeat such crashes in my local devices, it happens in about 2% of users, on Androids 5.0+.

**UPDATE**:
I am sure that this bug is related to the AdMob version of the plug-in and "something else". At the moment I was able to reduce the number of errors by 10-30 times. I reinstalled Windows and all software, in the end I left AdMob plugin version 3.14 and the rest of the software as described above. Now I have a new fatal exception (the example is below), but it occurs 1-2 times for 1000 players, it is tolerable.

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 2018.3.0f2
Device model      : samsung SM-G570F
Device fingerprint: samsung/on5xeltejv/on5xelte:8.0.0/R16NW/G570FXXU1CRK1:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.nativeProxyInvoke (Native Method)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$1.invoke (Unknown Source:6)
  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke (Proxy.java:913)
  at $Proxy10.onAdFailedToLoad (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.unity.ads.Interstitial$1$1.onAdFailedToLoad (Interstitial.java:75)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzjf.onAdFailedToLoad (Unknown Source:2)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzki.dispatchTransaction (Unknown Source:29)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzek.onTransact (Unknown Source:22)
  at android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:612)
  at oe.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):15)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.ac.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):6)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.a.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):335)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.a.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):331)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.a.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):140)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.c.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):44)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.j.run (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):2)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at ze.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):5)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):5)
  at ze.dispatchMessage (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):4)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6942)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Look at this topic: https://forum.unity.com/threads/crashes-on-android-after-migrating-to-unity-2018-3-when-use-androidjavaproxy-class.627637/ waiting for solution in the next Unity update